# Extracting rows from selected column in repeated/grouped data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`B`) given below which contains some repeated entries for various ids (`x_1`). For each id in x_1, I'm interested in extracting rows which have minimum values (as well as their repeats) in the second column (`z_1`). For example, for `A1`, I would like to extract rows 5 and 6. I would also like to keep rows that don't have more than 1 value under the `z_1` column-for example, all other entries apart from A1 and B10 should be included in the ouput.

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "B500", "B500", "C100", "C100", "C100", "D40", "D40", "G100", "G100")
z_1 <- c(rep(1.87, 2), rep(1.56, 2), rep(1.15, 2), rep(1.60, 2), rep(1.44, 2), rep(1.34, 2), rep(1.50, 3), rep(1.90, 2), rep(1.59, 2))
z_2 <- c( c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1), c(0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4), c(0.3, 0.6), c(0.6, 1.2, 1.8), c(0.25, 0.5), c(0.15, 0.3))
```

Here's the dataframe:

`B <- data.frame(x_1, z_1, z_2)`

```
x_1  z_1  z_2
 A1  1.87 0.50
 A1  1.87 1.00
 A1  1.56 0.50
 A1  1.56 1.00
 A1  1.15 0.50
 A1  1.15 1.00
B10  1.60 0.20
B10  1.60 0.40
B10  1.44 0.20
B10  1.44 0.40
B500 1.34 0.30
B500 1.34 0.60
C100 1.50 0.60
C100 1.50 1.20
C100 1.50 1.80
D40  1.90 0.25
D40  1.90 0.50
G100 1.59 0.15
G100 1.59 0.30
```

Here's the result I would like to obtain:

```
y_1  d_1  d_2
A1   1.15 0.50
A1   1.15 1.00
B10  1.44 0.20
B10  1.44 0.40
B500 1.34 0.30
B500 1.34 0.60
C100 1.50 0.60
C100 1.50 1.20
C100 1.50 1.80
D40  1.90 0.25
D40  1.90 0.50
G100 1.59 0.15
G100 1.59 0.30
```

Just to add that I've tried a few things which I found from other similar posted questions but none of these is giving the desired output:

```
aggregate(grouped_B$x_1, by = list(grouped_B$z_1), min)
do.call("rbind", by(B, B$x_1, function(x) x[which.min(unique(x$z_1)), ]))
```

Also just to add that the data-frame I'm working on is a grouped data:

```
grouped_B <- groupedData(z_1 ~ z_2 | x_1,      
                         data = B, FUN = mean,
                         labels = list( x = "duration",
                         y = "height"), units = list("(years)"))
```

I would really appreciate any useful hints/codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple in base R as well:

```
result <- merge(B,aggregate(z_1~x_1,B,min))
result
#     x_1  z_1  z_2
# 1    A1 1.15 0.50
# 2    A1 1.15 1.00
# 3   B10 1.44 0.20
# 4   B10 1.44 0.40
# 5  B500 1.34 0.30
# 6  B500 1.34 0.60
# 7  C100 1.50 0.60
# 8  C100 1.50 1.20
# 9  C100 1.50 1.80
# 10  D40 1.90 0.25
# 11  D40 1.90 0.50
# 12 G100 1.59 0.15
# 13 G100 1.59 0.30
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer-does the job!

Answer (score 1):

If each row in your data set is unique, you could do this simply with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(B)[, min(z_1), by = c("x_1", "z_2")]
setnames(DT, 1:3, c("y_1", "d_2", "d_1"))
#      y_1  d_2  d_1
#  1:   A1 0.50 1.15
#  2:   A1 1.00 1.15
#  3:  B10 0.20 1.44
#  4:  B10 0.40 1.44
#  5: B500 0.30 1.34
#  6: B500 0.60 1.34
#  7: C100 0.60 1.50
#  8: C100 1.20 1.50
#  9: C100 1.80 1.50
# 10:  D40 0.25 1.90
# 11:  D40 0.50 1.90
# 12: G100 0.15 1.59
# 13: G100 0.30 1.59
```

If it's not unique, could do

```
DT <- setDT(B)[, list(d_1 = z_1[grep(min(z_1), z_1)],
                d_2 = z_2[grep(min(z_1), z_1)]), by = c("x_1")]

#      x_1  d_1  d_2
#  1:   A1 1.15 0.50
#  2:   A1 1.15 1.00
#  3:  B10 1.44 0.20
#  4:  B10 1.44 0.40
#  5: B500 1.34 0.30
#  6: B500 1.34 0.60
#  7: C100 1.50 0.60
#  8: C100 1.50 1.20
#  9: C100 1.50 1.80
# 10:  D40 1.90 0.25
# 11:  D40 1.90 0.50
# 12: G100 1.59 0.15
# 13: G100 1.59 0.30
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I'm unable to replicate your results though-I think there's a problem with setDT-this function hasn't been defined. I'll definitely read more about data-table, seems like a really useful package.

Comment: @John, You need install/load package `data.table` first. There is no reason for `setDT` not to work

Comment: I've already installed this package prior to running that code-still same problem. The package is definitely installed-I've checked.

Comment: @John, did you `library(data.table)`? What error are you receiving? You can also replace `setDT(B)` with `data.table(B)` (less efficient though)

Comment: I've typed library(data.table) too. This is the error I'm getting-Error: could not find function "setDT"

Comment: Probably you have an old version of `data.table` package. Either update it or just switch `setDT(B)` to `data.table(B)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'll do that.